# Isomorphism between cohomology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $(S^3, *), (S^5, *)\in Top_*$ be two spheres. We have $S^3 \vee S^5 = S^3 \times \{*\} \cup \{*\} \times S^5.$ The project map $\pi: S^3 \vee S^5\to S^3$ a continuous. Hence $\pi$ reduced to cohomology group isomorphism $$\pi^*: \mathbb{Z}/2\cong H^3(S^3; \mathbb{Z}/2) \to H^3(S^3\vee S^5; \mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2.$$

My question is why $\pi^*$ an isomorphism??

I hope that someone, can help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Consider the obvious map $q:S^3\to S^3\vee S^5$. The composition $\pi\circ q$ is the identity map of $S^3$. Can you use this for something?

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Álvarez. We have $id = (\pi\circ q)^* = q^*\circ \pi^*$ and $id = (q\circ \pi)^* = \pi^*\circ q^* ,$ so $\pi^*$ an isomorphism.right or wrong?

Comment: One of the two compositions is not the identity.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Álvarez. Yes! How to prove $\pi^*$ an isomorphism?

Comment: Well, use my hint.

Comment: @ Mariano Suárez-Álvarez. I don't understand. Can you explain for me?

Comment: I suggest you think about this for a longer time. There is no hurry.